# How to correctly embed Cognito Forms into secure pages (SSL)

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm trying to secure a form page on our site, which is using Cognitoform's javascript for embedding the form. I have our entire site secured with SSL, but am getting an SSL validation error that points to services.cognitoforms.com. (Using whynopadlock.com to test.)

Is there anything I can do to prevent this error?

---

EDIT: Somehow this resolved itself. Never mind...

Answer (score 1):

All pages and content for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) are always served over HTTPS.  For example, clicking this link:

http://www.cognitoforms.com

will automatically redirect you to:

https://www.cognitoforms.com

**However**, if you add images to your forms by specifying a URL to your images from your website, instead of uploading your images, these links must also be HTTPS.  If they are not, you will receive a security warning.

If this is not the problem in your case, please submit a support request so we can take a look at your specific form, and please provide a link to where your form is embedded in your secure website.

https://www.cognitoforms.com/support

Comment: Also, when using a service like No Padlock, both the smart captcha and user session tokenization used by Cognito Forms likely prevents this service from accurately reporting results.  The best way to investigate this is to press F12 and click on the Network tab in developer tools to see what requests are either not encrypted or return errors.  In this case, Cognito Forms is both encrypted and working correctly.